# mvn install or package fails because unable to find symbols from another package in workspace

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-2, maven-3

I have a spring boot project `Proj-Main` and another project which contains entity classes called `Proj-Entities`. Both of these are present locally. I have added the latter as a dependency of the first. It works perfectly in my IDE (in my case STS) however when i try to create a jar to deploy to server using `mvn package` or even `mvn install` for `Proj-Main`, it fails to find classes which are present inside `Proj-Entities`. I have checked my `.m2` directory and I am able to find the jar for `Proj-Entities` there. I have tried standard clean and rebuild techniques but it just doesn't seem to work.

This is how i am adding dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.proj</groupId>
        <artifactId>Proj-Entities</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

My build task looks like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding the following build goals to the `Proj-Entities` pom.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add modules section in rout proj-main. In the module section add

`<module>../Proj-Entities</module>`

Then do "mvn clean install" in your Proj-Main . You will get a war file and a jar file in your target folder.

Or you can try this

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.proj</groupId>
     <artifactId>Proj-Entities</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/Proj-Entities-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

You can specify your jar file name according to your project.

`"systemPath" here, it requires the absolute path of the project.You can make it easier by keeping the file inside the project itself such that "basedir" will work`

Comment: Can you explain in detail with code example and reference links. On a cursory reading about modules, it doesn't seem to be the same thing that i am trying to do. What i understood was that modules are namespaces within the same project. In my case, i want to add a dependency to my project which is not present on maven central but present locally.

Comment: You solution unfortunately didn't work. However, i have solved it now. Check my answer.